# How to convert UTC to CST using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to convert the below time to CST. How can I achieve it using Jquery or Javascript? It should always display as a CST timezone.

```js
var date = new Date();
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var yy = date.getFullYear();
    var hh = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes;

    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hh >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hh = hh - 12;
    }
    if (hh == 0) {
        hh = 12;
    }
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var valsss = (mm) + "/" + dd + "/" + yy + hh + " " + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;
    $("#printDate").text(valsss);
```

```html
<p id= "#printDate"></p>
```

Comment: Do you have any limitations that would prevent you from using a time library like momentjs?

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with JS's `Date` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @OffDutyBlue we can use moment.js too

Answer (score 1):

Please check this below like can convert

```
d = new Date();

localTime = d.getTime();

localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

utc = localTime + localOffset;

offset = -5;

cst = utc + (3600000 * offset);

nd = new Date(cst);

newdate = (nd.toLocaleString());
$('#printDate').text(newdate + ' CST');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that the browser will change the displayed date to the user's timezone. I wrote this to grab a date in a kendo grid by a class on a td and set it to CST. In this case the server is in CST and I wanted the time say 12:00 to display as 12:00 for a user in MST not as 11:00 in MST. Hope it helps...

Checks User / Browser's timezone offset.
Get difference in hours from server timezone offset.
Looks at a column on the Kendo Grid with class .dbDate.
Grabs the grid date (displayedTime). 
Uses Moment.js to Convert (convertedTime) it based on the difference (diff) 
in hours we pass it. 
Formats convertedTime to the desired format i.e. 02/08/18 23:57.
Passes the Grid back the updated date and time.
Must Run Last on load.

```
function dateOffset() {
    var date = new Date();
    var offset;
    var diff;
    offset = date.getTimezoneOffset()
    if (offset > 360) { //360 = CST
        diff = +(offset - 360) / 60
    } else if (offset < 360) {
        diff = -(360 - offset) / 60
    } else {
        diff = 0
    }
$(".dbDate").each(function (i) {

    var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');
    var displayedTime = grid.dataSource.data()[i].TicketDateTime
    var convertedTime = new moment(displayedTime).add(diff, 'hours').toDate();
    var originalTime = moment(convertedTime).format("MM/DD/YY HH:mm");

    i + 1
    $(this).html(originalTime)
})
}
```